# MVC4, SimpleMembershipProvider, MySql and FluentNhibernate

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-4, fluent-nhibernate, simplemembership

I am trying to use SimpleMembership with MySql and I cant get it to work.
I downloaded the latest devart connector for MySql and followed the instructions on

http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/articles/extendedmembership-tutorial.html

The problem is that the WebSecurity class provided by devart, only has the InitializeDatabaseConnection method but it misses the rest of the methods WebMatrix.WebData has. (i.e UserExists(), CreateAccount(), etc )

Does anyone knows any implementation of WebSecurity alternative to WebMatrix.WebData?

Answer (score 0):

We have implemented the InitializeDatabaseConnection method in the Devart.Common.Web.WebSecurity class because there was no way to override the corresponding method of the WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity class.

Other methods of the WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity class are supported in our implementation and can be used with Devart's SimpleMembership provider.

Comment: Hi, I have a question for you can you help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317146/simplemembership-with-fluentnhibernate-in-mysql-without-devart-providers